# Capture everything if delimiter is not found

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a set of strings:

```
first part#2nd part
a part
1st part#
#2nd part
```

If the string has a '`#`' delimiter, I need to capture all the subsequent characters. If the string has no '`#`' delimiter, I need to capture every single character within the string. [Link to example](https://regex101.com/r/ZD5a5C/3/).

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `^(?:[^#]*#)?(.*)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/ZD5a5C/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[^#]*#)?(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZD5a5C/4).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^#]*#)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 0 or more chars other than `#` and then a `#`
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.